# checking for keyCode 13 in multiple text areas

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page that has multiple forms depending on what group is being processed.  All the forms are basically the same (I just inherited this project so I have not had a chance to try to convert to OOP) with a text area for additional notes.  The issue is sometimes people are making lists separated by using return(enter).
text area mark-up:

```
    <label for="banote">Additional Note</label>
    <textarea id="banote" name="banote" class="addNote" rows="3" cols="35"></textarea>
```

Using Javascript and JQuery, I am attempting to prevent that by means of an alert box to start:

JS:

```
$('#banote').keydown(function (e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $('#banote').css('border', '1px solid red');
    alert("Do not use the return key in this field");
}
});
```

As written it works, but i don't want to have to write a separate script for each text are id.  there are 4  different fields like this one.  I tried to use a class and then replace the $('#banote') with $(.addNote') and that did not work.  How can I do this without repeating myself?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a css class selector should work

```
$('.addNote').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
        alert("Do not use the return key in this field");
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/claudioredi/p739Luv4/)

Comment: Thanks! My first try I was using (this).keydown(function(e){...})

Answer (score 1):

Returning false will disallow the return altogether, otherwise you'll prompt them to not use it but allow it

```
$('.addNote').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

[**jsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/p739Luv4/1/)

Comment: I was going to implement this as well, and i got a strict warning that an anonymous function does not always return a value...